# how to reset selected dropdown when its hide

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
select dropdown with diffrent output dropdown value
```

-- select an option -- 
                                    Unifi
                                    Streamyx

when select unifi it will show another dropdown for unifi package only

when select streamyx it will show another dropdown for streamyx package only

```
 <div class="form-group" id="beb">
                          <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">  Package List :
                          </label>
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                             <select name="PACKAGE_ID_UNIFI" class="form-control" onmousedown="this.value='';" onchange="jsFunction(this.value);">
                                <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                                <?php
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from unifi ORDER BY PACKAGE_NAME ASC");
                                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                                    {?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row["no"]; ?>"> <?php echo $row["PACKAGE_NAME"]; ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                        ?>
                             </select>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                        <div class="form-group" id="bob">
                          <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">  Package List :
                          </label>
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                             <select name="PACKAGE_ID_STREAMYX" class="form-control" onmousedown="this.value='';" onchange="jsFunction(this.value);" >
                                <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                                <?php
                                $result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from streamyx ORDER BY PACKAGE_NAME ASC");
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                                    {?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row["PACKAGE_NAME"]; ?>"> <?php echo $row["PACKAGE_NAME"]; ?></option>
                                 <?php
                                    }
                                 ?>
                             </select>
                          </div>
                       </div>
```

this is the javascript to hide the dropdown based on what selected

```
<script>    var a = document.getElementById('beb');
   if ((value) == 'UNIFI') 
  {
       a.style.display = '';
   } 
  else if((value) == 'STREAMYX')
  {
       a.style.display = 'none';
   }



 var a = document.getElementById('bob');
   if ((value) == 'UNIFI') 
  {
       a.style.display = 'none';
   } 
  else if((value) == 'STREAMYX')
  {
       a.style.display = '';
   }

      </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to select the first item (-- select an option --) in the selectbox.
You could do this with:

```
$('select[name="PACKAGE_ID_UNIFI"]').prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

and

```
 $('select[name="PACKAGE_ID_STREAMYX"]').prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

I've added ID's to the select boxes so they are easyer to target in jquery:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#streamSelect').change(function(){
    if( this.value === 'unifi'){
      $('#unifi-contaioner').removeClass('hidden');   // show the unifi selectbox
      $('#streamyx-contaioner').addClass('hidden');   // hide the streamyx selectbox
      $('#streamyx').prop('selectedIndex',0);         // reset the streamyx selectbox
    }else{
      $('#streamyx-contaioner').removeClass('hidden');  // show the streamyx selectbox
      $('#unifi-contaioner').addClass('hidden');        // hide the unifi selectbox
      $('#unifi').prop('selectedIndex',0);              // reset the unifi selectbox
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.hidden{
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="streamSelect">
    <option value="unifi">unifi</option>
    <option value="streamyx">streamyx</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="unifi-contaioner">
  <label for="unifi">Package List unifi:</label>
  <select id="unifi" name="PACKAGE_ID_UNIFI">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="streamyx-contaioner" class="hidden">
  <label for="streamyx">Package List streamyx:</label>
  <select id="streamyx" name="PACKAGE_ID_STREAMYX" >
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect user selection using the change event. You are using pure hs but also tagged jQuery. I will give the example in jQuery as that's what you should be using if you already have both on the page.

Your example also has several issues. Use seperate variables for different elements. The hiding doesn't make sense to me. I will do the example for beb anyway but I think you should rereview your question.

Instead of changing the css it would be cleaner to have a selected class in css.

```
var $beb = $('#beb');
var $bob = $('#bob');

$beb.on('change', function (e) {
      $beb.toggleClass('selected');
});

function
```